# How do I trigger an event with a specific game object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers

I have a problem with a trigger. Basicaly I want the the trigger to work only when the player pass on it. But if an enemy collide with it or a bullet collide with it, it gets activated. I tried to put a tag on the player but it doesn't seems to work because the trigger doesn't recognize the player or the bullet shooted from his gun.
Here is the script:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class StartTrigger : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject Player;
 
     public GameObject Spawns;
 
     public GameObject Trigger;
 
 
     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
         {
             Spawns.SetActive(true);
         }
         
     }
 
     void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         Trigger.SetActive(false);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         print("Something entered the trigger");
         if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
         {
             print("Player entered the trigger");
             Spawns.SetActive(true);
         }
     }
    
     void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         print("Something has exit the trigger");
         if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
         {
             print("Player has exit the trigger");
             Trigger.SetActive(false);
         }
     }
```

If my code not working:

1. Make sure that you have tag on the player
2. Check tag spelling in code